# async/await in a Javascript promise

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a situation where I need to use async methods as both the resolve and reject functions of a Javascript(jQuery) promise. The function `updateThingy` was originally non async and the need for it to be async is only a recent thing, this method is used further up the stack with a `.then()` after it, hence it returns a Promise.

Obviously it would be great if I could refactor the jQuery promise, but there isn't time at the moment, hopefully there is another way, consider the following:

```
async function updateThingy() {
    var thing = await common.indexDbStorage.getThingy();

    if (window.state.online) {

        return updateServer() //<-- this returns a jQuery ajax result
            .then(_updateLocal, _serverUpdateFailed);

    } else {
        await _updateLocal();

        return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
    }

    async function _updateLocal() {
        //other things
        await common.indexDbStorage.updateThingy();
    }

    async function _serverUpdateFailed() {
        //other things
        await common.someOtherAsyncFunction();
    }   
}
```

The idea here is that if we ever lose connection, `window.state.online` will be set to false and we stop sending requests to the server, we always want to save it locally.

What I'm seeing is that `_updateLocal` never runs.

Comment: Are you ever not online? Does `getThingy()` throw an error, do you ever land in `_serverUpdateFailed` then?

Comment: If `_updateLocal` never runs, then probably `updateServer()` returns a promise that never fulfills. Can you please post its implementation?

Comment: You really should just drop `return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();`, maybe in favour of the equivalent `return undefined;` if you want to be explicit.

Comment: Quite a few scenarios here where you could just be returning the Promise as opposed to awaiting them internally.